# How to convert several non-adjacent columns to lowercase

Tags: excel, vba

This is looping through a worksheet that is about 10k rows and it is taking a considerable amount of time. Is there a way to do this faster aside from an array?   thank you

```
For i = 2 To spberowcnt
    With spbe30
    .Range("b" & i).Value = LCase(.Range("b" & i).Value)
    .Range("d" & i).Value = LCase(.Range("d" & i).Value)
    .Range("i" & i).Value = LCase(.Range("i" & i).Value)
    .Range("j" & i).Value = LCase(.Range("j" & i).Value)
    .Range("l" & i).Value = LCase(.Range("l" & i).Value)
    .Range("m" & i).Value = LCase(.Range("m" & i).Value)
    .Range("n" & i).Value = LCase(.Range("n" & i).Value)
    .Range("p" & i).Value = LCase(.Range("p" & i).Value)
    .Range("q" & i).Value = LCase(.Range("q" & i).Value)
    .Range("r" & i).Value = LCase(.Range("r" & i).Value)
    .Range("z" & i).Value = LCase(.Range("z" & i).Value)
    .Range("aa" & i).Value = LCase(.Range("aa" & i).Value)
    End With
Next i

For i = 2 To spberowcnt
    With spbe60
    .Range("b" & i).Value = LCase(.Range("b" & i).Value)
    .Range("d" & i).Value = LCase(.Range("d" & i).Value)
    .Range("i" & i).Value = LCase(.Range("i" & i).Value)
    .Range("j" & i).Value = LCase(.Range("j" & i).Value)
    .Range("l" & i).Value = LCase(.Range("l" & i).Value)
    .Range("m" & i).Value = LCase(.Range("m" & i).Value)
    .Range("n" & i).Value = LCase(.Range("n" & i).Value)
    .Range("p" & i).Value = LCase(.Range("p" & i).Value)
    .Range("q" & i).Value = LCase(.Range("q" & i).Value)
    .Range("r" & i).Value = LCase(.Range("r" & i).Value)
    .Range("z" & i).Value = LCase(.Range("z" & i).Value)
    .Range("aa" & i).Value = LCase(.Range("aa" & i).Value)
    End With
Next i
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use an array? That's exactly the way to go.

Comment: Perhaps using `Evaluate` and `Lower`.

Comment: @BigBen; Would guess that it would take even longer.

Comment: Are you using setting `Application.ScreenUpdating = false` for the duration of the `for` loops? If not, that will speed up your process significantly.

Comment: @FunThomas - I meant get rid of the loop and use `Evaluate` and `Lower` on the entire column.

Comment: Can you use evaluate for the entire column? Didn't know that, yes then it would be faster. Anyhow, still don't see the point in not using arrays

Comment: @FunThomas - yes you can use Evaluate on a multi-cell range but I completely agree with you, there's no point in not using an array.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following, looping over the *columns* instead of the individual cells and using `Evaluate` and `Lower` on the entire column. You could also process adjacent columns together.

```
cols = Array("B", "D", "I:J", "L:N", "P:R", "Z:AA")

For i = LBound(cols) to Ubound(cols)
    Dim col As String
    col = cols(i)

    With spbe30
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = .Rows("2:" & spberowcnt).Columns(col)

        rng.Value = .Evaluate("LOWER(" & rng.Address & ")")
    End With
Next
```

But as mentioned in comments, an array is probably the way to go.

Comment: would doing like this in combination with an array be even better yet?

Comment: Probably not, in my opinion. I don't see how adding an array would improve this.

Comment: @anarchocaps note this works also `cols = Array("B", "D", "I:J", "L:N", "P:R", "Z:AA")`

Comment: Good point, didn't even think about that, edited.

Answer (score 0):

This is the array solution

```vb
Sub test()


Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Dim arrWorksheets(1) As Variant, ws As Worksheet
Set arrWorksheets(0) = spbe30
Set arrWorksheets(1) = spbe60

Dim arrColumns As Variant
arrColumns = Array("B", "D", "AA")  'adjust to your needs

Dim arrValues As Variant

Dim iWs As Long, iC As Long, i As Long

For iWs = 0 To UBound(arrWorksheets)
    Set ws = arrWorksheets(iWs)
    
    For iC = 0 To UBound(arrColumns)
        arrValues = ws.Range(arrColumns(iC) & "2").Resize(spberowcnt).Value
    
        For i = 1 To UBound(arrValues, 1)
            arrValues(i, 1) = LCase(arrValues(i, 1))
        Next
        
        ws.Range(arrColumns(iC) & "2").Resize(spberowcnt).Value = arrValues
    Next
Next
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Alternative: helper columns ...